# Series : Every rearrangement converges $\implies$ absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I know that for a (complex) series : If the series converge absolutely, then every rearrangement also converges and converge to the same limit.

But how to prove the converse : If every rearrangement of a (complex) series converge to the same limit, then the series itself also converge absolutely. That is to prove :

Let $\sum z_i$ be a complex series. If every rearrangement of $\sum z_i$ converge to the same limit, then $\sum z_i$ converges absolutely.

Comment: No, the contrapositive is that if $\sum|z_i|$ does not converge, then either there is a divergent rearrangement, or there are two rearrangements converging to different limits.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely and $b_n$ and $c_n$ are any two rearrangement  of $a_n$ then is it true that $\sum |b_n|=\sum |c_n|$?

Comment: @MeetPatel: Yes: if $\sum_n a_n$ converges absolutely, then so does $\sum_n|a_n|$, so every rearrangement of $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges to the same limit as $\sum_n|a_n|$.

Answer (score 5):

The contrapositive of your statement follows from the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

---

To be more precise, suppose for a contradiction that $\sum z_i$ is a sum that is convergent under every rearrangement to the same limit $\ell$, but it is not absolutely convergent. Then $\sum|\Re z_i|+\sum|\Im z_i|\ge \sum|z_i|=\infty$, so either $\sum\Re z_i$ or $\sum\Im z_i$ is a conditionally convergent real series, so the Riemann series theorem gives a rearrangement $\sigma$ such that one of these two converges to something different from their original sum, and then $\sum z_{\sigma(i)}=\sum\Re z_{\sigma(i)}+\sum\Im z_{\sigma(i)}\ne\ell$ in contradiction to the hypothesis.

Comment: That theorem is for real series, so it doesn’t directly apply here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I added more details. (You can also use the "Steinitz's theorem" extension mentioned on wiki to get the complex version directly.)